# Returning blank if part of the formula is blank

Tags: excel-formula

I need what is probably a simple formula, but eludes me at this time.  My formula is simply something like =I9-F9.   However if F9 is blank I want the cell with the results to remain blank as opposed to a fraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ISBLANK` generally returns `TRUE`, if the cell `F9` contains blank which is returned as part of another formula. For example see below,

[image]

I have used a formula to check if cell `A1` is `1` and print `""` in cell `B1`. The cell `B1` actually seems to be a blank cell, but it is not. See below,

[image]

The best way to check for blanks in your case is to,

```
=IF(F9="","",I9-F9)
```

Comment: Agreed!  Thanks for  your response.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

=`IF(ISBLANK(F9),"",I9-F9)`