# Incorrect If formula

Tags: excel

As I'm still getting the hang of excel I'm not 100% sure why this formula isn't working!

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(L6),ISBLANK(M6)),"";IF( L6 >= M2,"True","False")
```

I'm trying to do a true, false check for cols L and M but as there are blanks in there I need to check for them as well. For the blanks, I just want to make them "".

Comment: you are missing braces, and also the delimiter is `;` and `,`. Either one should be used.

Comment: Try this =IF(OR(ISBLANK(L6),ISBLANK(M6)),"",IF(L6>=M2,"True","False"))

Comment: Thanks, guys it works now. Much appreciated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44526019/returning-blank-if-part-of-the-formula-is-blank/44526742#44526742 This might be helpful

Answer (score 1):

- As per [Gowtham's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45008141/incorrect-if-formula#comment76989851_45008141), you are missing some brackets.
- Use `,` **or** `;` to delimit parts of the `IF` statement. Not both.
- `true` and `false` are special words in Excel. They do not need to have quotes `"` around them like regular strings.

---

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(L6),ISBLANK(M6)),"",IF(A1>B1,TRUE,FALSE))
```

**Edit**
As per jsheeran's comment this can be simplified further as Excel will automatically evaluate `A1>B1` to `true` or `false`.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(L6),ISBLANK(M6)),"",A1>B1)
```

Comment: Oh, I see thanks for explaining that to me. It works now, much appreciated

Comment: `IF(A1>B1,TRUE,FALSE)` is redundant, because the expression `A1>B1` will resolve to `TRUE` or `FALSE` on its own.

Comment: @jsheeran Very true - added to answer.